# View differences between AX 2012 environments

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

I have two Dynamics AX 2012 environments (Test and Live). Multiple developers from multiple companies have been making uncoordinated changes to the two environments without version control. Before upgrading the two environments to R2 I would like to get an overview of the differences between the AOTs of the two environments, to avoid overwriting work-in-progress on testing or moving unfinished features to production.

What is the most efficient way of comparing two AX 2012 environments?

Comment: I was coming to ask this very same question. You beat me by a day. You can do a schema compare on the database to at least get some information, but hopefully someone has an answer for the rest of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works, not ideal, but works.

Export what you want to compare from each environment and then use a compare tool, (I use Beyond Compare) to compare the resulting XPOs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered initializing a baseline modelstore database, then treating the code like an upgrade? Export the models from one of the ax 2012 environments and performing the code upgrade checklist? I'd check the whitepapers on customer source/partner source if you have access, although they may even be on technet. I believe you can import models and create a comparison project.